# AJAX request between subdomains is taking forever

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request, plupload

I use plupload to upload an image from subdomain1.domain.com to subdomain2.domain.com.
This request takes for over 2 minutes for 1 100kb image.
When an ajax request is made to get some data from subdomain2.domain.com, it's done within seconds.
Why is it taking so long to upload such a small image?
The problem:

1. Click on an option to fetch html with plupload
2. html is loaded within seconds
3. From that html, click on a button to upload an image
4. Request is taking over 2 minutes to do nothing

The request never ends, even if I put a `die()` function at line 1, it just won't load.
Any ideas how to fix this?

-- edit --

All was working well before those files were transferred to different subdomains.

-- edit 2 --

This is the request that never finishes, it always stays pending
[image: This request seems to be made because it is cross browser]
This is the request that never finishes, it always stays pending
[image: This is the request that never finishes, it always stays pending]

Comment: server-side: right on the upload folder? Capacity? How do you process the "button to upload"?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell: It used to work without using subdomains. What do you mean by "How do you process the "button to upload"?"? I use plupload, when I click the button, I add 1 file to upload, once I've selected the file, upload starts automatically.

Comment: If you want to do a "upload button", that means you want to allow a client (web surfer) to deposit a file on your server, right?

So, I am wondering how is configured your server, if it has enought space, etc. Do you have any idea of it configuration?

Comment: Yes, there is around 100GB available. File/ folder permissions are 777 (just for testing). I think it is because the browser sees it as crossdomain, but I don't know if that is correct, and if it is, how to fix that.

Comment: Do you have access to the messages log (stuff like /var/log/httpd/error.log). If it is a problem of cross domain (CORS) you may find it with your browser by looking at the developper console (aka. firebug for firefox)

Comment: I can't see anything in the log files that I can access. What I see in my console, I will update my question with it because I can't upload images this way.

Comment: At least you can access the console: can you ask the available disk capacity? (on linux see "df -h"). I am wondering if your temporary folder is full (/tmp or /temp).

Keep in mind that's only one possible cause, there may be a lot of others (like an error in PHP and/or JavaScript code)

Comment: If the temp folder was full, the request should at least finish right?  I was told 125Gb is still available. When I put a die("test") at line of of that file, it still won't load. Also, this problem is since the files are running on different subdomains.